# How to get all Images src's of some html

Tags: c#, regex, image

I use this

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(sometext, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

to get an images src.

But how do I can get all src what I can find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use Regex.Matches instead of Match, and you should add the Multiline option I believe:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(sometext, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline))
{
    string src = m.Groups[1].Value;
    // add src to some array
}
```