# Getting String location of image in an html

Tags: html, parsing

I want to be able to get the src image from this html. At first I was thinking regex patern and matcher but I can't seem to figure out how do I get it. I operate on JAVA.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class="calibre">
<div class="calibre1">
<div class="s">
<p class="calibre2">
<img class="calibre3" src="0001.jpg"/>
</p>
<br id="calibre_pb_0" class="calibre4"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

String a;
Output : a = "src="0001.jpg""

Comment: How are you trying to obtain it? Script running on the page? Is this the input to a text parser?

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: Do not attempt to use RegEx to parse HTML. If you do, Tony the Pony will devour your soul: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I am using Java sorry for not posting it out.

Comment: @Polynomial I just wanted the src="item" image. I don't have to use a parser.

Comment: I used pattern and matcher to find the item check out my answer at the bottom. I didn't use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the solution for a more generalized question, try to adapt the for loop instead to look for what you specifically need: 
[How to get all Images src's of some html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538737/how-to-get-all-images-srcs-of-some-html)

Comment: good to know that you reached the answer you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use the following to get src on click

```
$("img").click(function() {
alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n63HE/5/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question was actually really easy. [Basic uses of pattern and matcher.](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/40regular_expressions/26pattern-matcher.html)

Here is a sample code of how I got the String "src="0001.jpg"".

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=(.*?)/");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
        if(m.find()){
            String item_found = m.group();
            Log.i("Image Found!", item_found);
        }
```

Again I would like to apologize about forgetting what programming language I use and yes never parse html with regex unless you need to. I just wanted to find a specific item within an html.

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML parser or the browser's Document Object Model and get the value from the Attribute interface for the `src` in "`<img class="calibre3" src="0001.jpg"/>`".

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery/javascript to get the src of img. I you want to do by such thing then send me reply

Answer (score 0):

Why just not using Javascript `getElementsByTagName()`?